# "resolved after call" or "resolved over call"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A person had a query and I answered his query over skype call. and I had to put comment in a CRM. and I put the following comment

> X's query resolved **over** Skype Conversation

and now I am thinking it should be

> X's query resolved **after** Skype Conversation

which one is correct or what will be more suitable for this sentence.

Comment: You already found a better alternative - 'x's query **resolved** via/over/through/on Skype' I think any of those "directions" would do. The only one I wouldn't use is 'after', because presumably their issue was resolved during the call, not after it. For 'tech-speak' customer support etc, I'd also use 'issue' rather than query. No-one, of course, ever calls anything a 'problem' in tech-speak, it's always an issue ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've upvoted your comment, but would add that "after" would be okay in cases where the problem was reported during the Skype call, and then fixed shortly after the call had ended. (In fact, it would even be acceptable in cases where it was fixed during the call; the important details are that the problem was there before the call started, and that it was gone after the call was over. Most native speakers wouldn't give a second thought to such usages.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in an early comment, there is no single preposition that should be used at the exclusion of all others. This is a case where a small handful of prepositions could be used, and quite a few would sound idiomatic and grammatical. For example, it you want to emphasize that the problem was resolved while the customer was on Skype with the technician, you could say any of these:

- ...resolved **over** Skype call
- ...resolved **during** Skype call
- ...resolved **via** Skype call
- ...resolved **by** Skype call
- ...resolved **on** Skype call
- ...resolved **through** Skype call
- ...resolved **with** Skype call

whereas if you simply want to emphasize that, after the Skype call was over, there all issues had been resolved, you could use:

- ...resolved **after** Skype call

Why do so many prepositions work? Mostly because many prepositions are flexible words with multiple meanings, some of which are overlapping, especially in the context of communication. For example, if you are **on** the telephone, then information is being shared **over** the phone line **during** the conversation, that is, while you are conversing **with** the other person.